# How can I use "addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()" to parse a string to Json feed Url to search the any Item as the user types on the editText

Tags: android, json, search, textwatcher, rotten-tomatoes

The loadToolBar method in MainActivity

```
public void loadToolBarSearch() {


        /*ArrayList<String> countryStored = SharedPreference.loadList(Search_Activity.this, Utils.PREFS_NAME, Utils.KEY_COUNTRIES);*/

        View view = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_toolbar_search, null);
        LinearLayout parentToolbarSearch = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.parent_toolbar_search);
        ImageView imgToolBack = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_tool_back);
        final EditText edtToolSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_tool_search);
        ImageView imgToolMic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_tool_mic);
        /*final ListView listSearch = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_search);*/
        /*final TextView txtEmpty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_empty);*/

        /*Utils.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listSearch);*/

        edtToolSearch.setHint("Search your country");

        final Dialog toolbarSearchDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.MaterialSearch);
        toolbarSearchDialog.setContentView(view);
        toolbarSearchDialog.setCancelable(false);
        toolbarSearchDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        toolbarSearchDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        toolbarSearchDialog.show();

        toolbarSearchDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);


        edtToolSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
edtToolSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


    }
});

            }
        });

        imgToolBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toolbarSearchDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        imgToolMic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                edtToolSearch.setText("");

            }
        });
```

The Search UrlClass

```
  public class Endpoints   {

    public static String getRequestUrlSearchMovies(int limit) {


        return "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=54wzfswsa4qmjg8hjwa64d4c&q="+"**StringToBeSearched**" +"&limit=30";

    }
}
```

This is where all search functions are executed

```
public class MovieUtils {

    public static ArrayList<Movie> loadSearchMovies(RequestQueue requestQueue) {
        JSONObject response = Requestor.sendRequestBoxOfficeMovies(requestQueue, Endpoints.getRequestUrlSearchMovies(30));
        ArrayList<Movie> listMovies = Parser.parseMoviesJSON(response);
        /*MyApplication.getWritableDatabase().insertMovies(MovieDatabase.UPCOMING, listMovies, true);*/
        return listMovies;
    }
}
```

I need to know how I can make this code work such that when the users are typing the Item to search the search will be triggered as they type

> (searching dynamically)

, and how to search an Item once the user press

> DONE

on the Keyboard. 
Any one with a better Idea on how to make this search logic work? 
Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some serious issues here!. You should remove the onClickListener generation. You should just respond to text change events:

```
edtToolSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           //DO SEARCH HERE (MAY NEED TO LIMIT HTTP REQUESTS THOUGH
       }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           //OR DO SEARCH HERE AFTER USER STOPS TYPING (LESS HTTP REQUESTS),
        }

   });
```

Comment: As for the search class itself, you will need to accept the String generated in the edit text to the search function. Then you will need to make an HTTP Post with Volley or Async task. Android does not use AJAX out of the box.

Comment: Have you been able to return a search from a web service?

Comment: No, To my opinion my main issues is that I am not able to Parse a string from TextWatcher to Endpoint class, the Url class..How do I do this, Or Do you have better Ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: Why don't we start a chat. There is so much wrong here, I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Apparently I can't proceed to a chat because I only have 15point. How are going to solve this?

Comment: I believe that I answered your original question, but it still does not solve the fact that you are missing almost every other aspect to make your search work. Do your homework before posting a question like this.